# Compasion of two approaches of exponentiating elements of a matrix

Tags: performance, numpy, jax

I have two approaches of exponentiating a matrix in `jnp = jax.numpy`. A
straightforward one:

```
jnp.exp(-X/reg)
```

And with some additional actions:

```
def exp_reg(X, reg):
    K = jnp.empty_like(X)
    K = jnp.divide(X, -reg)
    return jnp.exp(K)
```

However, when I tested them:

```
%timeit jnp.exp(-X/reg).block_until_ready()
%timeit exp_reg(X, reg).block_until_ready()
```

The second approach turned to outperform, despite having superficially some additional overhead. I've run a `%timeit` with a matrix of size 2000 x 2000:

```
7.85 ms ± 567 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.19 ms ± 52.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Why it may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is order of operations.

In `jnp.exp(-X/reg)`, you are negating every entry of `X`, and then dividing each entry of the result by `reg`. That's two passes over the array `X`.

in `exp_reg` you are negating `reg` (which presumably is a scalar value?) and then dividing `X` by the result. That's one pass over `X`.

If `X` is large, I would expect the first approach to be slightly slower than the second, due to the multiple passes over `X`.

Fortunately, since you're using JAX, you can `jit` compile your code, in which case XLA generally can optimize over equivalent orders of operation like these. Indeed, for your two functions, compilation eliminates the discrepancy:

```python
from jax import jit
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

def exp_reg1(X, reg):
  return jnp.exp(-X/reg)

def exp_reg2(X, reg):
  K = jnp.divide(X, -reg)
  return jnp.exp(K)

X = jnp.array(np.random.rand(1000, 1000))
reg = 2.0

%timeit exp_reg1(X, reg)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.17 ms per loop
%timeit exp_reg2(X, reg)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop

# Trigger compilation
jit(exp_reg1)(X, reg)
jit(exp_reg2)(X, reg)

%timeit jit(exp_reg1)(X, reg)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.92 ms per loop
%timeit jit(exp_reg2)(X, reg)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop
```

(side note: there's no reason to pre-allocate an empty array `K` before assigning the result of an operation to a variable of the same name).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: how does the exponentiation of the elements of a matrix compare to the matrix exponential? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: @develarist I was not interested in the **matrix** exponent, I asked for the elementwise exponentiation

Comment: I know, but why would one opt for element-wise exponentiation as opposed to the exponential of the matrix

Comment: @develarist in order to fulfil your curiosity I would tell about the actual reason. The sinkhorn iterations for the optimal transport problem use the *elementwise* exponentiation of the elements.

Comment: i never even realized that the sinkhorn algorithm nor the sinkhorn distance even used exponentiation. exponenantiation of which matrix exactly? the distance matrix or transport matrix? And actually that doesn't answer the question of *why* they are choosing to exponentiate elements of a matrix, rather than exponentiating the matrix itself. You're just saying they do it without any reason whatsoever